# C: use fwrite to write char to different line

Tags: c, linux, file-io, fwrite

I have to write to a file as follows:

```
 A
 B
 C
 D
 ...
```

Each character of the alphabet needs to be written to different line in the file. I have the following program which writes characters one after another:

```
 FILE* fp;
 fp = fopen("file1","a+");
 int i;
 char ch= 'A';
 for(i=0; i<26; i++){
     fwrite(&ch, sizeof(char), 1, fp);
     ch++;
 }
 fclose(fp);
```

How should I change the above program to write each character to a new line. (I tried writing "\n" after each character, but when I view the file using VI editor or ghex tool, I see extra characters; I am looking for a way so that vi editor will show file exactly as shown above).

I tried using the following after first fwrite:

```
 fwrite("\n", sizeof("\n"), 1, fp);
```

Thanks.

Comment: By writing "\n" after each character, did you do another fwrite or something else?

Comment: Could you show the modified code that writes `\n`s? Was it something like `fwrite("\n", sizeof(char), 1, fp);`?..

Comment: Is there some reason that you need to use fwrite? fwrite is intended for binary data, and to write text you usually use fprintf and putc.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
fwrite("\n", sizeof("\n"), 1, fp);
```

should be

```
fwrite("\n", sizeof(char), 1, fp);
```

Otherwise, you are writing an extra `\0` that is part of zero-termination of your `"\n"` string constant (`sizeof("\n")` is two, not one).

Answer (score 2):

What "extra characters" do you see? You do realize that the `"a+"` parameter to `fopen` opens the file for appending, so that you're writing to the end of the file. Did you perhaps mean `"w+"`, which will overwrite the file?

You could use:

```
fputc((int)ch, fp);
fputc((int)'\n', fp);
```

Or even `fprintf(fp, "%c\n", ch);`